# Find by equals() in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have object address entity with the overridden equals() and hashCode():

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class ObjectAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    
    private String country;
    
    private String region;
    
    private String county;
    
    private String settlement;
    
    private String district;
    
    private String street;
    
    private String houseNumber;
    
    private String building;
    
    private Integer apartmentNumber;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ObjectAdress that = (ObjectAdress) o;
        return Objects.equals(country, that.country) && Objects.equals(region, that.region) && Objects.equals(county, that.county) && Objects.equals(settlement, that.settlement) && Objects.equals(district, that.district) && Objects.equals(street, that.street) && Objects.equals(houseNumber, that.houseNumber) && Objects.equals(building, that.building) && Objects.equals(apartmentNumber, that.apartmentNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(country, region, county, settlement, district, street, houseNumber, building, apartmentNumber);
    }
}
```

A user sends me a request to register their property at the specified address. I want to check that this object hasn't been registered yet. But I don't know the id. And I want to find the corresponding object in my DB according to equals() and hashCode() methods using JPA repository.

How can I achieve this (if I don't want to manually specify all the fields)?

Comment: without knowing the `id` of the user, you might not be able to do what you want. Getting the `id` from the client is not a big deal, if you can do that. It'll simplify your whole problem.

Comment: Client wants to register a new object, which may not be saved in DB yet and may not have an id. I just want to verify that the object at the specified address definitely wasn't saved yet. So I don't know the id

Comment: "*And I want to find the corresponding object in my DB according to equals() and hashCode() methods using JPA repository.*" - You do realize that this would entail that we have to transfer and map the entire database table, yes? The database has no notion of `equals()` and `hashCode()`; we'd need to do this in the application. In other words: the entire table has to be transferred to the application, and each row has to be mapped to a java object.

Comment: Well, now I use this JPA method:

`Optional<ObjectAddress> findByCountryAndRegionAndCountyAndSettlementAndDistrictAndStreetAndHouseNumberAndBuildingAndApartmentNumber(String country, String region, String county, String settlement, String district, String street, String houseNumber, String building,
            int apartmentNumber);`

I think, it is converted into an SQL query with long WHEN statement. Of course It's executed by DBMS. And it doesn't fetch all the data from the table.

I just want to know if I can use a little syntactic sugar instead of this long and ugly method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use `hashCode()` and `equals()` via your JPA repository, you have the option of defining a new column on your entity. You can simply add a field like so:

```java
@Setter(accessLevel = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
private String uniqueAddressCode = String.valueOf(this.hashCode());
```

Update your table's schema to add this field, and now you can query by `uniqueAddressCode` using your JPA repository to locate duplicate address records.

Note that you will need to handle cases where the address is updated, and cases where different users enter the exact same address, leading to a clashing `hashCode`. Towards that end, I'd recommend adding the user ID as a part of the `hashCode` evaluation.

Comment: This is dangerous. The `hashCode()` function does neither define an address, nor is it guaranteed to be unique. Even if we add the address to the hashing function, it is not guaranteed that the hash code is unique. We could prefix the hash code with the address, this would, however, require that we need the id to query the hash code.